# python not recognizing variable in if statement

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to name a variable inside an if statement. Any bit of information will help (I cut the beginning of code because it all works until I want to display cost) p.s it's a homework assignment

Comment: They all need to be defined in order for them all to be displayed.  As it is currently written, you define only a couple variables in each `elif`.  You can use defaults by defining them all before all of the `if` and `elif`'s

Comment: What zondo said. However, I suspect that you should have two separate `if... elif` blocks. So change  `elif month =="july":` to  `if month =="july":`, and put a blank line before it so people reading your code can easily see that it has two separate `if... elif` blocks.

Comment: I disagree with the downvotes. A complete newbie will have such problems as not defining variables. The problem is posed well enough to allow us to help.

Answer (score 2):

@Liz: The comments above are correct. You need to give values to the variables to execute your code.

```
x=1
a=2*x   # example for your code , after you defined the needed variable x
print a
```

In the example solution below I'm defining a function (see `def` keyword), which allows me to write your code without having defined the variables yet. 
So after I'm done with the function definition, I can then define the variables and execute the function.

```
def dosomething(x):   # your code in a function, you don't need to know x yet
    a=2*x
    return a

x=10   # now you know x and you want to use it in your function
print dosomething(x) # will print 20
```

I hope that helps with your understanding. Here your problem addressed:

```
def totals(cabin,month,n):
    if cabin == "inner cabin":
        cost = 400 * n
    elif cabin == "ocean view cabin":
        cost= 800 * n
    elif cabin =="balcony":
        cost= 1200 * n

    # the if-block for the months is separate from the loop for the cost
    if month =="july":
        tip= 10*5*n
        subtotal= cost + tip  # add tips
    elif month=="june":
        tip= 10* 5 * n
        cost1= cost + tip 
        cost2= cost1 * .10   # a 10% discount
        subtotal= cost1 - cost2
    elif month=="august":
        subtotal = cost    # no tip, no discount
    # there should be an else for other months
    return cost, subtotal

month='july'    
cabin='balcony'
n=2  # number of passengers
cost,subtotal = totals(cabin,month,n)

print  "\nMonth of vaction reservation:",month, \
"\nNumber of passengers:",n, \
"\nType of Cabin:",cabin, \
"\nCost of cabin:",cost, \
"Subtotal:",subtotal
```

output:

```
Month of vaction reservation: july 
Number of passengers: 2 
Type of Cabin: balcony 
Cost of cabin: 2400 Subtotal: 2500
```

You'll have to add the destination, which is yet another, separate decision, i.e. has to have it's own `if..elif..else` block, if that affects any of the pricing.

Comment: This is okay, but it's not an 'if loop' because it doesn't loop. Call it an 'if block' instead.

Comment: Thank you, my oversight. Fixed.

Comment: I changed the line breaking in the print statement based on JackW327s comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it worked before and you've defined your variables and given them appropriate values before you entered the if - elif statements ... it looks like your problem is that subtotal is spelled wrong in one place. Also, since this is a homework assignment, check your spelling of any real words. You've got one other one wrong that I can see.

Bonus point - figure out how to get the print line contained within 80 columns in the editor. Google PEP-8. Really long lines like that are just bad form.

Oh, all I did was correct the spelling on that variable and added this code above the code you supplied:

```
cabin = "inner cabin"
passangers = 200
Destination = "Rio"
month = "june"
subtotal = 0
```

I would also suggest that all your conditional actions be consistent. Tips, subtotals, etc. should be set in all of them in my opinion. That way you don't get totally different results for each condition, unless of course that was the assignment.

As the other answer points out, putting the repetitive parts in a function is the right way to go. However you might not be at functions yet in the course yet. I dunno.

Good luck & hang in there!